# spring boot request header validation against enum

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a spring boot application which has rest controller. Along with the payload i want to validate header values. For e.g there is a header called X-CLIENT-CODE. Now I have an enum of Client Codes. If I put the type of the header as the enum like ClientCodeEnum, then I am getting HTTP status code 500, instead i want 400 as its a BAD REQUEST.
Sample Code:

```
@PostMapping(value = {"/create"})
  public Mono<ResponseEntity<MyResponse>> create(
      @RequestBody @Valid final MyRequest myRequest,
      @RequestHeader(name = "X-CLIENT-CODE") @Valid final ClientCodeEnum clientCode) {
```

In this case I am getting Internal Server Error.
Error Logs:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader @javax.validation.Valid com.sample.ClientCodeEnum] for value 'ABC1'
```

Enum Code:

```
public enum ClientCodeEnum {

    ABC("ABC"),

    XYZ("XYZ");

    private String value;

  ClientCodeEnum(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
      return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return String.valueOf(value);
    }

    public static ClientCodeEnum fromValue(String value) {
      for (ClientCodeEnum b : ClientCodeEnum.values()) {
        if (b.value.equals(value)) {
          return b;
        }
      }

      throw new WrongHeaderValueException("Invalid '" + value + "'");
    }
}
```

I even have GlobalException handler annotated with RestControllerAdvice, where i am catching the WrongHeaderValueException, but that block is not executed as the Spring fails in String to Enum conversion.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is an valid enum? I fit cannot be converted it is already valid. So the `@Valid` on the header field is pretty much useless.

Comment: The `@Valid` is pretty much useless on a header field. The enum is correct or not. If it cannot be converted you will get an error. Your `fromValue` won't be called as the String will be converted using the regular enum conversion.

Comment: @M.Deinum, fine, I can get rid of it Valid annotation. So the only way will be to create a custom jsr validator and then raise the exception? is there anyway i can get out of the box like the payload validation?

Comment: A validator won't work because it simply will not be converted to an enum as it isn't a proper enum value. Without a custom converter for this specific enum it will use the default enum conversion.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use `HttpServletRequest` object to fetch header and validate**

Try something like below

1. Autowire a bean of type `"HttpServletRequest"` in your controller
2. Use `getHeader(String headerName)` to check it's value or if it's null

**Example**

```
PostMapping(value = {"/create"})
  public Mono<ResponseEntity<MyResponse>> create(
      @RequestBody @Valid final MyRequest myRequest,
      @RequestHeader(name = "X-CLIENT-CODE") @Valid final ClientCodeEnum clientCode) {

   String value=request.getHeader("X-CLIENT-CODE"); // Will return null if not passed
... }
```

Validate your value , Hopefully should work !